# Hilbert Space with two inner product and showing map $T_p$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

We have Hilbert Space $H$ with real inner product $H_1$ i.e $H,\langle .,. \rangle_{H_1}$ and there is another inner product $H_2$ on $H$ such that

$$\langle x,x \rangle_{H_1} \le \langle x,x \rangle _{H_2}$$

Now, let fix $ p \in H$ and define a map $T_p : H \to \mathbb R$ defined as $T_p(x)=\langle x,p \rangle_{H_1}$

I want to show $T_p$ is bounded linear functional on $H$. My attempt is following:

We say linear functional is bounded if $\exists c$ such that $||T_p(x)||_ {\mathbb R} \le c||x||_{H_1} $.

I had a problem to show this since we have two inner product. We know that norm on $\mathbb R$ is absolute value so $$|T_p (x)| = \langle x,p \rangle_{H_1} \le ||x||_ {H_1} ||p||_{H_1} $$

Last transition is from Cauchy-Schwarz then I said it is bounded but I am not sure about it.**!!!!**

By Riesz Representation Theorem we know that since $T_p$ is bounded (assume I showed it) then there is a $q \in H$ such that
$$\langle x,p \rangle_{H_1} \le \langle x,q \rangle _{H_2}$$

Now, my question is how can I say the map $T: H \to H$ defined as $p \to q$ is linear where $p,q$ stated above. I stucked with this because it doesn't look like $T_p$(I guess). What should I do?

Comment: Your proof that $T_p$ is bounded seems fine to me. C-S inequality is always true for any inner product. Then RIesz representation theorem tells you that for any $p\in H$, there exists a unique $q\in H$ such that
$$\langle x,p \rangle_{H_1} \color{red}{=} \langle x,q \rangle _{H_2} $$
So the map $T$ is well defined as well. Now you want to check that it is linear, so start by writing the properties that $T$ need to satisfy and explain where you are stuck

Comment: Do you assume that $H$ is complete also  with respect to  $\|\cdot \|_{H_2}$ ?

Comment: In exercises it is not mentioned that $H$ is complete. I am sorry, I made a mistake while I was writing equality that Riesz implies. @StratosFair, you are certainly right. I need to show $T$ is linear, to do this pick $x,y \in H$ and $\lambda$ as a scalar then $T(\lambda.x +y)=\lambda*T(x) + T(y)$.

Comment: $T(\lambda*x+y)=\langle \lambda*x+y,q \rangle_{H_2}$ and by inner product properties I can write it as $\lambda \langle x \rangle + \langle y \rangle = \lambda * T(x)+T(y)$. Okay, it seems okay but I haven't used the inner product property of $H_1$ and $H_2$. By the way, definition of $T$ is given by $p$ goes to $q$. What does this mean?

Comment: The continuity of $T_p$ on $H$ with respect to either norm does not require the Riesz representation theorem, just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. $$|T_px)|\le\|p\|_{H_1} \|x\|_{H_1}\le \|p\|_{H_1} \|x\|_{H_2}$$ Observe that  another functional $S_px=\langle x,p\rangle_{H_2}$ may not be continuous with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_{H_1}.$

Comment: The Riesz representation theorem holds only when the space is complete. So the existence of $q$ in your statement is not guaranteed unless the space $H$ is complete with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm.